# How to add an image inside primefaces inputText or inputNumber?

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I want to add an image inside the `<p:inputText>`.
The image is aligned to the left and the text itself is positioned at center.
What should I do to `<p:inputText>` to place the image inside it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is using InputGroup.

See example: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputGroup.xhtml

[image]